# Laravel 9 Digitalocean spaces upload file

Tags: laravel, digital-ocean-spaces

```
   $filename = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();


        Storage::disk('do')->put("public/images/{$directory}/{$filename}", File::get($file), 'public');

        return "images/avatars/{$filename}";
```

I upload file there is not any error but file doesn't upload to digitalocean spaces

Comment: Most likely an issue with your access/permission with the hosting provider. What error are you getting?

Comment: There is not any error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can u provide `do` disc configuration in `config/filesystems.php`